# Is lua-lru thread-safe?

Tags: lua, mod-lua

I found a Lua LRU cache implementation here [lua-lru](https://github.com/starius/lua-lru)

Is this thread-safe, can this be used with mod_lua?

Comment: This library did not share anything so yes. But i do not think you can use this library from several threads.

Comment: Vanilla Lua doesn't support threads, so "everything" is thread-safe. Most `mod_$LANGUAGE` Apache plugins, as far as I can tell, run separate processes for each request, so there's nothing to share anyway.

Comment: If modulewritten on C and use e.g. static variables then it may not be thread safe. But pure lua modules which do mot use any not thread safe libs are thread safe

Comment: @moteus Is there then any lru cache implementation that would work with mod_lua?

Comment: An alternative could be using mod_lua's inter vm cache instead of the map, to store the k-v pairs, and the size and the pointers, but then updating them in multi-thread would not be safe. Wondering if there's an alternative.